# Color Cyclic Permutations

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

Suppose there are n people sitting in a circle,wearing 3 kind of shirts  viz. white,red and green. When two people with different shirt color talk with each other, they both change their shirt to third color.

At i-th step, the 1st person talks with 2nd person, the 2nd talks with the 3rd ,… and the nth  talks with 1st person.

Given the original color of shirts of n persons,find the color of shirts of n person after k steps.

Eg:n=5 and k=4 and initial colors are WRWRW then after 4 steps ans is: GGGWG

I tried with some cases of my own but could not come up with general algorithm!!Kindly help me with this??

Comment: Could you show step-by-step how you get from WRWRW to GGGWG?

Comment: Take for eg:n=3 k=1 and initial is:GRR then final ans is RGR ( WWR,WGG,RGR)

Comment: I hope now you can understand how the ans came for wrwrw now after 4 steps:)

Comment: For the WRWRW after 1 step configuration will be GRRGG (GGWRW,GRRRW,GRRRW,GRRGG,GRRGG)  then continue again for this new configuration...to get the final ans after 4 steps